# avrdude OS error: cannot set attributes for port /dev/ttyS0: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, platformio, atmega32

I am new platformio and getting acquainted with arduino. I am trying to burn bootloader from platformio but not able to succeed. I am getting error :
avrdude OS error: cannot set attributes for port /dev/ttyS0: Inappropriate ioctl for device
avrdude error: unable to open programmer arduino on port /dev/ttyS0
Even though i am mentioning the port. Its's not workigng on that port but port /dev/ttyS0
Below is the screenshot. platform.ino looks like this:

```
[env:ATmega328P]
platform = atmelavr
board = ATmega328P
framework = arduino
lib_deps =
nadavmatalon/WatchDog@^1.2.0
lib_compat_mode = off
test_build_src = yes
upload_port = /dev/ttyUSB0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjBtS.png)

I am running pio run -t bootloader but it's not working. I mentioned the upload port in platform.ino but its still not working.